# Call a Function with parametric type while specifying the Type (Julia 0.5)

Tags: function, types, julia, function-call

(I am referring to Julia 0.5)
Lets say I define a function:

`f{T<:Real}(x::T=one(T), y::T=one(T)) = x+y`
And I want to call it while specifying the type, but without specifying it via the arguments. E.g. I want to do:
`f{Float64}()`
In the console this gives the error:

`ERROR: TypeError: Type{...} expression: expected Type{T}, got #f`

So, is it possible to call any function (besides constructors for parametric types) using the `{}` syntax **during the function call**?

EDIT: The reason I came up with this question is because I wanted to use default arguments but also specify the Type at the same time, something like `f{BigFloat}()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind writing `f(BigFloat)` instead of `f{BigFloat}()`, you could change your function definition to:

```
f{T}(args::T...) = f(T, args...)
f{T<:Real}(::Type{T}, x::T=one(T), y::T=one(T)) = x+y
```

Which allows you to specify a type if necessary while still letting you write `f(1,2)`.

Answer (score 2):

George,

When you call a parameterized function, the value that the parameter "picks up" is determined by the type[s] of the argument value[s] you place in the function call.  The information flow is from the given arguments to the symbolic type parameter.  So you should not be trying to call `f{AbstractFloat}(some_kind_of_number)`.  In that case `some_kind_of_number` may be e.g. Float64, and that comports; but it may be e.g. Int64, and then you have a conflict.

If you want to force the number variable to take on a specific numerical type, the right approach is to convert it directly or to define a conversion for that case (if it does not exist already).  If you want to trap that sort of mismatch, then the right approach is to pass in the type you want to specify along with the numeric variable:

```
# below
# x is of type Real or of any subtype of Real
# T is Real or any type that is a subtype of Real
# so T may or may not equal typeof(x)

function f{T<:Real}(::Type{T}, x::Real)  
    y = convert(T, x)
    return g(y)
end

function f{T<:Real}(::Type{T}, x::Real)
    if typeof(x) == T
       #...
    else
       throw(ErrorException("msg"))
    end
end
```

Let me know, with specifics, if you are trying to accomplish something else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am well aware about the `convert` function and type stability in general and your answer is not what I was looking for. I was looking for a way to pass the Type information into a function without giving it any actual arguments, besides some type information. The second answer to my question by Fabio was exactly what I wanted.